# Undefined omniauth_authorize_path method Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I'm building a rails app that has tables associations and after renaming a certain controller, view, and a model I got a No MethodError at /users/sign_in
undefined method `omniauth_authorize_path' for #<#:0x007fbb34f8ffb0>

Please find the code at: https://github.com/ReemAlattas/ActionTracker

I'm using devise for email and facebook authentication.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe this helps https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview#facebook-example

Answer (score 0):

Change `devise.rb` setup to this:

config/initializers/devise.rb

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  ....
  # Omniauth setup
  config.omniauth :facebook, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET'
  ....
end
```